# How to view any ".a" files in Vim?

Tags: vim, archive

I get a bunch of characters while viewing .a files in Vim. Any idea how .a files can be viewed properly in Vim?

Comment: That's an archive generated by the tool `ar`. You can list the contained files with `ar t foo.a` from a shell command line. (You can also run this in Vim using the standard shell command invocation operator `!`) You really don't want to do anything beyond that. If you do you may very well corrupt the file.

Comment: Oh, and read the man page for `ar` to learn other ways you can extract information from '.a' files.

Comment: For an example file such as `thing.a` please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/645086/edit) to provide the output of `file thing.a`